# Can't Flash SD Card

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to flash my SD card on my Mac and receive an error message in the Terminal:

Command entered:

```
sudo python raspiwrite.py

Response:
  File "raspiwrite.py", line 177
    else
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I downloaded the necessary files from github/exaviorn/RasPiWrite.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `else` statement in line 177 is missing a colon.

Open `raspiwrite.py` in TextEdit, scroll down to line 177, add a colon after `else`, and save the edited file.

Alternatively, you can [download my fixed version from Github](https://github.com/patricknc4pk/RasPiWrite/tree/patch-1).

I've submitted a pull request to the original author to fix the script.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I receive another error:  File "raspiwrite.py", line 275
    SDsnip =  SD.replace(' ', '')[:-1]
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: pushed another commit that should fix this; does it work now?

Comment: No, it now works better but I receive the message: No, I now receive the message: Checking for updates...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raspiwrite.py", line 440, in <module>
    checkforUpdate()
  File "raspiwrite.py", line 68, in checkforUpdate
    dom = parseString(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1924, in parseString
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
  File

Comment: "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 15, column 59        --> What am I doing wrong? Thanks!